# How to convert string including unrecognized timezone to datetime?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I need to parse a string into python datetime, the string received in this format - **Thu Jul 15 12:57:35 AWST 2021**

I use below code to parse it

```
datetime.datetime.strptime("Thu Jul 15 12:57:35 AWST 2021", "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
```

It triggers error - "*ValueError: time data 'Thu Jul 15 12:57:35 AWST 2021' does not match format '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y'*"

The problem is timezone AWST is not recognized by using **%Z**, according to [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior)

```
%Z
In strftime(), %Z is replaced by an empty string if tzname() returns None; otherwise %Z is replaced by the returned value, which must be a string.

strptime() only accepts certain values for %Z:

any value in time.tzname for your machine’s locale

the hard-coded values UTC and GMT
```

How can I parse this string properly? BTW, I am using python 3.8.2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will the input always be in `AWST` timezone or could it contain string with different timezones ?

Comment: AWST is one example, it could be other timezones @heretolearn

Comment: if there is a timezone that is equal to AWST and recognized by python, you could replace AWST in the string using `replace()` to the recognized timezone, and your code would work

Comment: I'd rather leave this as the last option as it's not just AWST been used

Comment: Note: abbreviated time zone names can be ambiguous (see e.g. https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/), which makes parsing them difficult. Therefore, Python's `%Z` is very limited (GMT, UTC).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handling timezone could be a bit tricky. One option could be to make a map of the interested timezone from https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/ and then use `dateutils.parser` to parse the date.
Something like :

**Using UTC Offset:**

```
from dateutil import parser

# Creating a sample map for the timezone abbreviation and the offset
timezone_info = {
        "A": 1 * 3600,
        "AT": -4 * 3600,
        "AWDT": 9 * 3600,
        "AWST": 8 * 3600,
        "AZOST": 0 * 3600,
        "AZOT": -1 * 3600,
        "AZST": 5 * 3600,
        "AZT": 4 * 3600,
        "AoE": -12 * 3600,
        "B": 2 * 3600,
        "BNT": 8 * 3600,
        "BST": 6 * 3600,
        "C": 3 * 3600,
        "CAST": 8 * 3600,
        "CET": 1 * 3600,
        "W": -10 * 3600,
        "WEST": 1 * 3600,
        "WET": 0 * 3600,
        "WST": 14 * 3600,
        "Z": 0 * 3600,
}

#Date String
date = "Thu Jul 15 12:57:35 AWST 2021"

# parse the timezone info from the date string
tz = date.split(" ")[-2] # Assuming the date format is"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
parser.parse(date, tzinfos={tz : timezone_info.get(tz)})
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 15, 12, 57, 35, tzinfo=tzoffset('AWST', 28800))
```

**Using IANA Time Zone Names** :
(As suggested by @MrFuppes in the comments)

```
from dateutil import parser

# Creating a sample map for the timezone abbreviation and the offset
timezone_info = {
    "AWST": 'Australia/Perth',
    "BNT": 'Asia/Brunei',
    "CAST": 'Antarctica/Casey',
    "CET": 'Europe/Paris'
}

#Date String
date = "Thu Jul 15 12:57:35 AWST 2021"

# parse the timezone info from the date string
tz = date.split(" ")[-2] # Assuming the date format is"%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"
parser.parse(date, tzinfos={tz : timezone_info.get(tz)})
```

**Output:**

```
datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 15, 12, 57, 35, tzinfo=tzstr('Australia/Perth'))
```

Comment: Why use fixed UTC offsets? While this is correct in principle, you could also map IANA time zone names, e.g. `'AWST': 'Australia/Perth'` so that for example timedelta arithmetic works correctly over periods that include DST transitions

Comment: @MrFuppes, Yes you are correct, we can use the IANA time zone names to create the map as well instead of UTC offset. Like i mentioned in the beginning of my answer, this is just one of the options. What i wanted to highlight in my answer was the `map creation` and use of `dateutils.parser` to parse the date. The offset can change based on the requirement.

Comment: yup, feel free to add the IANA time zone name option. As I've commented on the question, the point here is that abbreviated time zone names can be ambiguous (check out *BST* for example (-; ), which his why `%Z` can't *just parse* them. It's a relatively common question here on SO since people expect exactly that.

Comment: Thanks for all your suggestions